# Fast_Gettext Not Displaying Translations in Rails 3.2.13 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, locale, gettext, i18n-gem

I have PO files (en.po & fr.po) that I want to use to localize my Rails application into French.  I submitted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203622/translating-a-rails-application-3-2-13-using-po-gettext-files recently to see if I could get any help.  I mentioned that I had read some information about Fast-Gettext and another gem. I decided to look at the Fast-Gettext gem since it allows the use of PO files without using a database.

I added the latest versions of fast_gettext and gettext_i18n_rails in my Gemfile.  I installed the latter gem to get rid of an undefined method "_" error message even though I have no plans at this point to use the database feature.

I added the following code in config/application.rb.

```
# add FastGettext configuration
FastGettext.add_text_domain 'my_app', :path => 'config/locales', :type => :po, :ignore_fuzzy => true, :report_warning => false
FastGettext.default_text_domain = 'my_app' # set the default textdomain
FastGettext.default_available_locales = ["en","fr"] # set available locales # (note: the first one is used as a fallback if you try to set an unavailable locale)
FastGettext.default_locale = 'en'
```

Here is my setup in application_controller.rb to allow the locale to be set and saved using a cookie.

```
include FastGettext::Translation

before_filter :set_users_locale

def set_users_locale
  I18n.locale = FastGettext.set_locale(params[:locale] || cookies[:locale] ||
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] || 'en')
  cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale.to_s
end
```

I added logic where the user can click a flag and set the value of :locale.

```
<%= link_to_unless_current image_tag("flag_us_30px.jpg", :alt => "Set Language to English"), locale: "en" %>
<%= link_to_unless_current image_tag("flag_fr_30px.jpg", :alt => "Set Language to French"), locale: "fr" %>
```

When a person clicks the flag it sets the value of :locale correctly.  I have my routes formatted as domain.com/:locale/link.  Right now the root will include the locale until I add logic to override it.

Here are two statements in my views that I am testing with:

```
<%= _("Language") %>

<%= _("Note: If you do not understand the text on the icons, use the text links at the bottom of the page.") %>
```

When I click the French flag to change the value of :locale to "fr" the link changes properly but the code for both strings remains in English.  The PO file has the French translation for both of these terms.  I would think that if it had not found the PO files that I should be seeing error messages stating it did not find them.

I first attempted to use the configuration code in config/initializers/fast_gettext.rb but did not get any results so I decided to put it in config/application.rb to see if I could get it to work.  I also removed ':ignore_fuzzy => true, :report_warning => false' to see if that may change things.  However I get the same results.

I am using fast_gettext because back in 2011 @svenfuchs recommended it for using Gettext.  I may try and contact him on Twitter since it looks like that is the only place I can find where he is active these days.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using PO files instead of common [Rails translations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)? 
Or the [globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) if you prefer to save the translations on database and add model translations.
There's also a gem to help you converting your existing translations: [i18n-translators-tools](https://github.com/pejuko/i18n-translators-tools).

Comment: I found a 2010 video by Sven Fuchs that mentioned Gettext and that it was old:) In 2011 he recommended fast_gettext in a response on another Stack Overflow post. The PO files have a initial translation already. According to the documentation it can process PO files but I can't get it to work. I saw globalize3 mentioned in my research.  It looks I would have to write an interface for DB maintenance which I was trying to avoid.  I will take a look at i18n-translator-tools. I may try the database first.  If all else fails I will convert to yaml files. Thanks so much for your input, Paulo.

Comment: After checking all the other options I have decided to use the Simple translation tool with yaml files to do the translation.  Since I have all my translation data in spreadsheets I will just add a column with the labels I will use in the yaml files instead of using the i18n-translator-tools.  By the time I got the gem set up I could quickly create csv files, reformat them and copy the code into the yaml files.  Again thanks so much for your input, Pablo.